# Sum JSON objects and get a JSON file in Python

Tags: python, json, sum

I have a JSON file with many objects. I want to filter it to discard all the objects that does not have a specific field called ´id´. I developed a piece of code but it does not work:

```
import json
b=open("all.json","r")
sytems_objs=json.loads(b.read())
flag=0
for i in range(len(sytems_objs)):
    if sytems_objs[i]["id"]<>None:
        if flag==0:
            total=sytems_objs[i]
            flag=1
        else:
            total=total+sytems_objs[i]

file1=open("filtered.json","w+")
json.dump(total, file1)

c=open("filtered.json","r")
sytems_objs2=json.loads(b.read())
```

I get a Error: `ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you meaning to open `filtered.json` in append mode? you typically cant do that and expect it to be a valid json you get back

Comment: Do you want something like: [`echo '[{"a":1, "id": null}, {"id": 123, "a":2}, {"a":3}]' | ./jq 'map(select(has("id")))'`](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/) or `echo ... | ./jq 'map(select(.id))'`?

Comment: That I want is create other JSON file with only the emelents that have the item `id` different than null. So in your example it would be `[ {"id": 123, "a":2}]` because is the only one that has a `id` element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that system_objs is originally an array of objects

```
system_objs = json.loads(b.read())

# create a list that only have dicts with the property 'id'
# just read the comment to also include if id is not null
system_objs = [o for o in system_objs if 'id' in o and o['id'] is not None]

# how many dicts have 'id' with it
print len(system_objs)

# write the system objs to a json file
with open('filtered.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(system_objs))
```

Comment: you could use `json.load(b)` and `json.dump(system_objs, f)`. Also valid `id`s have probably [true values](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) i.e., you could simplify the test: `L = [o for o in L if o.get('id')]`.